# Jasmine: testing my rails site's interface with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, jasmine

I've been looking for ways to test a Rails 3 app that has quite a lot of JS code for its rich interface. I tried with Capybara, but that didn't work out, so now I'm giving Jasmine a try. But I'm having a hard time understanding how I should go about it.

From what I gathered, Jasmine alone is good for testing the JS components of a site, but what if I want to test the interface directly? I need something like:

```
describe "Sign in" 
   Visit '/home'
   When user clicks "Sign in" link 
   The sign in form should appear
```

Can I actually do something like that with Jasmine? So far, my tests are included on a results page generated by the rails-jasmine gem and obviously they run over that DOM, not over my site's DOM.

I'm now trying to use evergreen, but I get the same result (I can't even include jQuery).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - no, Jasmine will not inherently function in a way which will let you navigate your site and test at such a high level, like an integration test with Cucumber.

Jasmine is built primarily to test the API of your js, and so essentially you will only be able to test URL routes or something with it if they are part of your API.

For example, you can test how a Backbone Router will respond to your window's current location, or navigating from one location to the next, but that is because Backbone Routers explicitly handle URL locations.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

Comment: That really doens't answer my question. I was asking for a Javascript framework to do things like that. I've already tried Capybara and it doens't work for me (I don't know if it's because my site has too much JS or what). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `jasminerice` with fixtures. If the intent is to test the JS DOM interaction, then fixtures would be the way to go.
But if the idea is to test the server interactions as well, then going with something like `cucumber` makes sense.